# Articles with the names of pop stars and a word "concert" - which sentences are correct?

Tags: articles, usage

Could you help me with a proper use of articles?

> **A.** I was at **a** Madonna concert in London last week.
>
> **B.** I was at **a** Madonna'**s** concert in London last week.
>
> **C.** I was at Madonna concert in London last week.
>
> **D.** I was at **a** Madonna'**s** concert in London last week.

What about names and surnames?

> **E.** I was at **an** Ewa Farna concert in London last week.
>
> **F.** I was at **an** Ewa Farna'**s** concert in London last week.
>
> **G.** I was at Ewa Farna concert in London last week.
>
> **H.** I was at Ewa Farna'**s** concert in London last week.

And finally what about bands, especially in plural or in foreign language?

Wilki in English means (Wolves)

> **I.** I was at **a** Wilki concert in London last week.
>
> **J.** I was at Wilki concert in London last week.
>
> **K.** I was at Wilki'**s** concert in London last week.
>
> **L.** I was at **a** Scorpions concert in London last week.
>
> **M.** I was at Scorpions concert in London last week.
>
> **N.** I was at Scorpions' concert in London last week.
>
> **O.** I was at Scorpions'**s** concert in London last week.

Which versions are correct? What should I use?

Could you provide a good explanation?

Comment: The name doesn't matter. The determiner modifies the word _concert,_ not the name that precedes it.

Answer (score 4):

It's either:

> I was at **a** Madonna concert last week.

or:

> I was at Madonna**'s** concert last week.

(You should use either an article or the possessive, but not both.)

The correct sentences in your question are A, E, H, I, K, L, and N. (Some might find O an acceptable alternative to N; consult your favorite [style guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe#apostrophes_showing_possession) for more information.)

---

As a footnote, the definite article can also be used:

> I was at **the** Madonna concert last week.

(That version would be more likely if the listener already had prior knowledge of the concert.)

Comment: What about names in plural like in the last example? Wilki means Wolves, so it's plural. Is "a" acceptable?

Comment: The "a" modifies concert, not the name of the group. _I was at a Talking  Heads concert last night_. The only reason "a" would not be acceptable is if you went to two (or more) concerts, but even then you'd use "a" when listing them individually. _I went to two concerts last week: a Ramones concert and a Black Keys concert_. (As you can see, the "a" has nothing to do with the group's name being plural.)

Comment: I don't know why "Madonna concert" conveys to me a concert whose name is Madonna. Especially with the definite article.

Comment: @Cardinal - No doubt there is room for ambiguity. If I said, "I was at a Winthrop concert last week," then _Winthrop_ could be the name of an individual, the name of the performing group, the name of the venue or concert series, or even the name of the town where the concert was held. Presumably, common knowledge between speaker and listener would remove the confusion.

Comment: @user46036 - You accepted this answer [way too quickly](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). (Somebody might want to explain why _I went to the Ramones' concert last week_ is acceptable.)

Comment: @J.R. You didn't address _"I was at [Scorpions'/Scorpions's] concert in London last week."_ Heaven knows we need a dust up about apostrophes and the Saxon genitive around this joint.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Yup, I was just saying something of the sort in my comment. The matter is hardly settled, much less the dust :-)