# Articles with the names of films - which sentences are correct?

Tags: articles, usage

> **A.** I was at **a** Shrek film last week.
>
> **B.** I was at Shrek'**s** film last week.
>
> **C.** I was at Shrek film last week.

Which versions are correct? What about the name with article "the"

> **D.** I was at **a** The Shark film last week.

or
simply

> **E.** I was at The Shark film last week.

Edit: I would like to ask about the last two examples because they contain the article "the" in the title.

Comment: The name of the film does not matter. The article modifies the noun _film._ This is identical to your previous question. Both _concert_ and _film_ are nouns.  Possible duplicate of [Articles with the names of pop stars and a word "concert" - which sentences are correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/articles-with-the-names-of-pop-stars-and-a-word-concert-which-sentences-are)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Actually, I think the questions are related, but not duplicates. Sentence B makes it sound like Shrek is the name of the actor or producer, not the main character. The so-called [duplicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/133239/113) indicates we can say, "I was at Madonna's concert last night," but I don't think "I was at Shrek's film last week" works quite the same way. There are some interesting nuggets here, especially for learners.

Comment: @J.R. No native speaker would ever say sentence B! (and I think the best outcome for future searchers is to have borth questions in one....) Thing is, I'm not sure that the OP understands that the article modifies the noun, not the attributive.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Of course no native speaker would ever say B! That's why I upvoted this as a useful question. Learners deserve an insightful answer explaining why.

Comment: @J.R. I think a comprehensive question, roughly "What article to use before [artist name/film title as attributive] + [name of venue]?" is probably here already, but I can't find it because search is not well implemented yet. I've moaned about this before. There's a host of useful material here that we have to stumble upon.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - That'll happen when you get 40,000 questions. It's a good problem to have. :-)

Comment: @J.R. It's a better problem than a dearth of material, but if we can't find the material through search, it's not of much value. Don't know the solution. Mandatory tagging? Smarter tags? Dunno.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The article *determines* the head nominal, it doesn't *modify* the noun.  Determiner and Modifier are two different functions a constituent can have.  Determiners, Modifiers, and Complements are all different kinds of Dependent (a more general function).

Comment: @snailplane I might have said "identifies" instead, I suppose, but there are so many sources that state things like _"An article is a word that identifies (or modifies) a noun"_ that I didn't think this was the place to raise the point. "Belongs to" is another choice, maybe, or (my favorite) _"is used alongside"_. My objective here is that the OP understand that, whatever the article does, it doesn't do it to the name of the film of artist. I like "determines the head nominal" and I'll put that in my quiver.

Comment: What if a title contains "The", for example: "The Ring"? Do we use the "I was at the The Ring film" or don't we use any article?

Answer (score 2):

If there's more than one such film (i.e. a franchise, or one work from a director's *oeuvre*), you can say "a" {name} film.

> I went to see a Hitchcock film last night.
>
> I went to see a Marx Brothers movie last night.
>
> I saw a Shrek movie last night.

If you're referring to one of several, and it is the one showing in "first-run" theaters now, you would use "the".

> I went to see the new Disney film last night.

If there is only one such film, you can use "the".

> I went to see the film about the shrinking polar ice cap which was
>   advertised with a full page spread in the Sunday New York Times.

Comment: What if a title contains "The", for example: "The Ring"? Do we use the "I was at the The Ring film" or don't we use any article?

Comment: no,  we do not repeat the article.